# Google Maps code breaking plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I am having trouble with a plugin breaking when I have google maps embedded in the website. I have made a copy of the page without the googlemaps code, and the plugin works - I can't figure out why when I add the code it breaks the plugin.

Expected behavior: 
[Clicking the respective fields will show a pop up where you can choose a date or time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnY6X.png)

Experienced behavior:
[Clicking the field yields no pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPIQ9.png)

The plugin that is breaking (found near the bottom of both examples):

```
            <script>
            $('#basicExample .time').timepicker({
                'showDuration': true,
                'timeFormat': 'H:i:s',
                'step': 60
            });

            $('#basicExample .date').datepicker({
                'format': 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                'autoclose': true
            });

            var basicExampleEl = document.getElementById('basicExample');
            var datepair = new Datepair(basicExampleEl);
        </script>
```

Code before:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Historical Data - CrowdTracker</title>
<link href="CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<title>Datepair.js &ndash; Demos and Documentation</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A javascript plugin for intelligently selecting date and time ranges inspired by Google Calendar." />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css" />

    <script src="lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />

    <script src="lib/pikaday.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/pikaday.css" />

    <script src="lib/jquery.ptTimeSelect.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jquery.ptTimeSelect.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <script src="lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/site.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/site.css" />

    <script src="dist/datepair.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/jquery.datepair.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

    alert("API Loaded");

    var ConData = new Array();
    var colour = [];
    var stroke = [];

    var lightgreen = '#D8FE6D'
    var darkgreen = '#8AE62E';
    var yellow = '#FFFF00';
    var orange = '#FFAD33';
    var darkorange = '#CF7C00';
    var red = '#ff3333';
    var darkred = '#990000';

    var line_light_green = '#97B24C';
    var line_dark_green = '#61A120';
    var line_yellow = '#B2B200';
    var line_orange = '#CC8A29';
    var line_darkorange = '#A16100';
    var line_red = '#B22424';
    var line_darkred = '#6B0000';

    var lime = '#00FF00';
    var teal = '#00FFCC';
    var blue = '#0000FF';
    var purple = '#6600FF';
    var fuchsia = '#CC66FF';

    var myheart = '#000000';

    function loadData()
    {
        var dateFrom = document.getElementById("dateFrom").value;
        var dateTo = document.getElementById("dateTo").value;
        var timeFrom = document.getElementById("timeFrom").value;
        var timeTo = document.getElementById("timeTo").value;

        temp = [dateFrom, timeFrom];
        datetimeFrom =  temp.join(" ");

        temp = [dateTo, timeTo];
        datetimeTo =  temp.join(" ");

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 

        else  
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","getHistoryData.php?q="+datetimeFrom+"&p="+datetimeTo+"&s="+dateTo,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {


            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
                temp = xmlhttp.responseText; //This returns the <doctype HTML> crap
                test = temp.split(">"); //Splitting the string into an array so that the number is the first in the 3rd array       

                alert(temp);

                for (x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
                {
                    test.shift();
                    test.pop();
                }

                for (s = 0; s <46; s++)
                {
                        ConData[s] = test[s];
                }

                /*
                function AlertValues(){ 
                alert(ConData[1]);
                alert(ConData[2]);
                alert(ConData[3]);
                alert(ConData[45]);
                }

                AlertValues(ConData);
                */

                /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/

                /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/


                for(i = 0; i < 46; i++)
                {   
                    if (test[i] > 0 &&  test[i] <= 100)
                    {
                        colour[i] = lightgreen;
                        stroke[i] = line_light_green;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 100 && test[i] <= 250)
                    {
                        colour[i] = darkgreen;
                        stroke[i] = line_dark_green;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 250 && test[i] <= 500)
                    {
                        colour[i] = yellow;
                        stroke[i] = line_yellow;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 500 && test[i] <= 750)
                    {
                        colour[i] = orange;
                        stroke[i] = line_orange;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 750 && test[i] <= 1250)
                    {
                        colour[i] = darkorange;
                        stroke[i] = line_darkorange;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 1250 && test[i] <= 2000)
                    {
                        colour[i] = red;
                        stroke[i] = line_red;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 2000)
                    {
                        colour[i] = darkred;
                        stroke[i] = line_darkred;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        colour[i] = myheart;
                        stroke[i] = line_red;
                    }
                }
            }
            return ConData;
        }
        return ConData
    }
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            setTimeout(function() { drawChart(ConData); }, 30000);


            function drawChart(){

                var Buildings = ['B01', 'B02', 'B03', 'B04', 'B05', 'B06', 'B07', 'B08', 'B09', 'B10', 
                'B11', 'B12', 'B13', 'B14', 'B15', 'B16', 'B17', 'B18', 'B19', 'B20',
                'B21', 'B22', 'B23', 'B24', 'B25', 'B27', 'B28', 'B30', 'B31', 'B31b',
                'B32', 'B35', 'B36', 'B37', 'B38', 'B39', 'B40', 'B41', 'B42', 'B43', 
                'B45', 'B63', 'B67', 'B68'];

                for (p = 0; p < 46; p++)
                {
                    ConData[p] = parseInt(ConData[p], 10);
                }

                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Building');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Users');
                for (f = 0; f < 46; f++)
                {
                    data.addRows([
                    [Buildings[f], ConData[f]]
                    ]);
                }

                // Set chart options
                var options = {'title':'Dispersion of students across campus',
                    'width':400,
                   'height':300};

                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }   
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
</div>
    <div id="navbar">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="LiveMaps.html">Live Maps</a></li>
            <li><a href="HistoricalData.html">Historical Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="Support.html">Support</a></li>
         </ul>        
</div>

  <section id="Titlebar"><a href="index.html"><img src="Images/Title.png" width="300" height="100" alt=""/></a></section>
  <section id="headergradient">
  <img src="Images/Grid.png" width="350" height="100" alt=""/>
<h1>Live congestion heat mapping and time data</h1>
  </section>

  <div id="wrapper"> 

    <main id="HistoricalData">&nbsp;

    <!-- HISTORICAL DATA STARTS HERE -->


    HISTORICAL DATA (SQL QUERIES VIA DROP DOWNS THAT PROVIDE DISPLAY DATA AND GRAPH API)



    <!-- HISTORICAL DATA ENDS HERE -->
    </main>

    <p id="basicExample">
        <input type="text" class="date start" id="dateFrom"/>
        <input type="text" class="time start" id="timeFrom"/> to
        <input type="text" class="time end" id="timeTo"/>
        <input type="text" class="date end" id="dateTo"/>
        <button onclick="loadData()"> Go </button>
    </p>

                <script>
                $('#basicExample .time').timepicker({
                    'showDuration': true,
                    'timeFormat': 'H:i:s',
                    'step': 60
                });

                $('#basicExample .date').datepicker({
                    'format': 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    'autoclose': true
                });

                var basicExampleEl = document.getElementById('basicExample');
                var datepair = new Datepair(basicExampleEl);
            </script>

</div>
<div id="chart_div" style="width:800; height:600"></div>
<footer id="DiversIT">
  <p id="DesignedBy">Designed by <a href="http://www.diversit.co" target="_blank">DiversIT</a></p>
  <p id="sitemap"><a href="SiteMap.html">Site Map</a></p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

After:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Historical Data - CrowdTracker</title>
<link href="CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style> 
#map 
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
}       
.info 
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 210px;
}
</style>


<title>Datepair.js &ndash; Demos and Documentation</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A javascript plugin for intelligently selecting date and time ranges inspired by Google Calendar." />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css" />

    <script src="lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />

    <script src="lib/pikaday.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/pikaday.css" />

    <script src="lib/jquery.ptTimeSelect.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jquery.ptTimeSelect.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <script src="lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/site.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/site.css" />

    <script src="dist/datepair.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/jquery.datepair.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&sensor=true_or_false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
            'modules':[{
              'name':'visualization',
              'version':'1',
              'packages':['corechart']
            }]
          }"></script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB5_KBtY0Pbm4aaRVk5-H0R3jZ2lfBhQNU"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_12);

      function drawChart_12() {
        var data_12 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Time', 'Users'],
          /*['9PM', 51],
          ['10PM', 32],
          ['11PM', 11],*/
          ['12AM',  2],
          ['1AM', 2],
          ['2AM', 2],
          ['3AM', 2],
          ['4AM', 3],
          ['5AM',  7],
          ['6AM', 18],
          ['7AM', 45],
          ['8AM', 50],
          ['9AM',  62],
          ['10AM', 87],
          ['11AM', 123],
          ['12PM', 135],
          ['1PM',  110],
          ['2PM', 104]/*,
          ['3PM', 101],
          ['4PM', 84],
          ['5PM',  64],
          ['6PM', 81],
          ['7PM', 72],
          ['8PM', 55],
          ['9PM',  42]*/
        ]);

        var options_12 = {
          title: 'Unibar (Building 12) - No. of users in past day',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          pointSize: 5,
          hAxis: {slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:45}
        };

        b12_div = document.createElement('div');
        b12_div.className = "info";
        b12_div.id = "b12_div";
        infoWindow_12 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var chart_12 = new google.visualization.LineChart(b12_div);
        chart_12.draw(data_12, options_12);
        infoWindow_12.setContent(b12_div);
      }
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    //google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

    //alert("API Loaded");

    //var ConData = new Array();
    var colour = [];
    var stroke = [];

    var lightgreen = '#D8FE6D';  // i > 0 && i <= 100
    var darkgreen = '#8AE62E'; // i > 100 && i <= 250
    var yellow = '#FFFF00'; // i > 250 && i <= 500
    var peach = '#FFCC99'; // i > 500 && i <= 750
    var orange = '#FFAD33'; // i > 750 && i <= 1250
    var darkorange = '#CF7C00'; // i > 1250 && i <= 2000
    var vDarkOrange = '#744600'; // i > 2000 && i <= 3000
    var red = '#ff3333'; // i > 3000 && i <= 4000
    var darkred = '#990000'; // i > 4000

    var line_light_green = '#97B24C';
    var line_dark_green = '#61A120';
    var line_yellow = '#B2B200';
    var line_peach = '#B8936E';
    var line_orange = '#CC8A29';
    var line_darkorange = '#A16100';
    var line_vdarkorange = '#513100';
    var line_red = '#B22424';
    var line_darkred = '#6B0000';

    var lime = '#00FF00';
    var teal = '#00FFCC';
    var blue = '#0000FF';
    var purple = '#6600FF';
    var fuchsia = '#CC66FF';

    var myheart = '#000000';

    function loadData()
    {
        var dateFrom = document.getElementById("dateFrom").value;
        var dateTo = document.getElementById("dateTo").value;
        var timeFrom = document.getElementById("timeFrom").value;
        var timeTo = document.getElementById("timeTo").value;

        temp = [dateFrom, timeFrom];
        datetimeFrom =  temp.join(" ");

        temp = [dateTo, timeTo];
        datetimeTo =  temp.join(" ");

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 

        else  
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","getHistoryData.php?q="+datetimeFrom+"&p="+datetimeTo+"&s="+dateTo,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {


            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
                temp = xmlhttp.responseText; //This returns the <doctype HTML> crap
                test = temp.split(">"); //Splitting the string into an array so that the number is the first in the 3rd array       

                alert(temp);

                for (x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
                {
                    test.shift();
                    test.pop();
                }

                for (s = 0; s <46; s++)
                {
                        ConData[s] = test[s];
                }

                /*
                function AlertValues(){ 
                alert(ConData[1]);
                alert(ConData[2]);
                alert(ConData[3]);
                alert(ConData[45]);
                }

                AlertValues(ConData);
                */

                /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/

                /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/


                for(i = 3; i <= 45; i++)
                {   
                    if (test[i] > 0 &&  test[i] <= 100)
                    {
                        colour[i] = lightgreen;
                        stroke[i] = line_light_green;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 100 && test[i] <= 250)
                    {
                        colour[i] = darkgreen;
                        stroke[i] = line_dark_green;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 250 && test[i] <= 500)
                    {
                        colour[i] = yellow;
                        stroke[i] = line_yellow;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 500 && test[i] <= 750)
                    {
                        colour[i] = peach;
                        stroke[i] = line_peach;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 750 && test[i] <= 1250)
                    {
                        colour[i] = orange;
                        stroke[i] = line_orange;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 1250 && test[i] <= 2000)
                    {
                        colour[i] = darkorange;
                        stroke[i] = line_darkorange;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 2000 && test[i] <= 3000)
                    {
                        colour[i] = vDarkOrange;
                        stroke[i] = line_vdarkorange;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 3000 && test[i] <= 4000)
                    {
                        colour[i] = red;
                        stroke[i] = line_red;
                    }
                    else if (test[i] > 4000)
                    {
                        colour[i] = darkred;
                        stroke[i] = line_darkred;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        colour[i] = myheart;
                        stroke[i] = line_red;
                    }
                }
                initMap();
            }
            //return ConData;
        }
        //return ConData
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initMap(); colourPickArray()">
<div>
</div>
    <div id="navbar">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="LiveMaps.html">Live Maps</a></li>
            <li><a href="HistoricalData.html">Historical Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="Support.html">Support</a></li>
         </ul>        
</div>

  <section id="Titlebar"><a href="index.html"><img src="Images/Title.png" width="300" height="100" alt=""/></a></section>
  <section id="headergradient">
  <img src="Images/Grid.png" width="350" height="100" alt=""/>
<h1>Live congestion heat mapping and time data</h1>
  </section>

  <div id="wrapper"> 

    <main id="HistoricalData">&nbsp;

    <!-- HISTORICAL DATA STARTS HERE -->


    HISTORICAL DATA (SQL QUERIES VIA DROP DOWNS THAT PROVIDE DISPLAY DATA AND GRAPH API)
     <!-- LIVE MAPS STARTS HERE -->

        <div align="center" id="map"></div>

        <script>
// Creates a map centered on UOW at specific zoom level.

function initMap() {

var mapStyles =[
    {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
        ]
    }
];

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    minZoom: 16,
    maxZoom: 20,
    zoom: 17,
    center: {lat: -34.4051998,lng: 150.8785557},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    styles: mapStyles
  });

  var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    // Southwest corner
    new google.maps.LatLng(-34.407490, 150.871661),
    // Northeast corner
    new google.maps.LatLng(-34.402622, 150.884642)
);

// Listen for the dragend event
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

// We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds
    var c = map.getCenter(),
    x = c.lng(),
    y = c.lat(),
    maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
    maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
    minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
    minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

    if (x < minX) x = minX;
    if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
    if (y < minY) y = minY;
    if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
});

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // Building 1  (Materials Engineering)
    var b1_coord = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(-34.406586,150.880995),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-34.406602,150.881127),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-34.407050,150.881050),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-34.407094,150.881411),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-34.407239,150.881385),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-34.407223,150.881221),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-34.407294,150.881208),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-34.407222,150.880619),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-34.406897,150.880676),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-34.406922,150.880900),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-34.406845,150.880912),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-34.406850,150.880948)
    ];

    var b1_poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        content: "Building 1",
        path: b1_coord,
        strokeColor: stroke[3],
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: colour[3],
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    });
    b1_poly.setMap(map);

    b1_poly.addListener('click', function(event) {  
           var contentString = this.content;  
           infoWindow.setContent(contentString);  
           infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);  
           infoWindow.open(map);
      });       
}

    </script> 


    <!-- HISTORICAL DATA ENDS HERE -->
    </main>
    <p id="basicExample">
        <input type="text" class="date start" id="dateFrom"/>
        <input type="text" class="time start" id="timeFrom"/> to
        <input type="text" class="time end" id="timeTo"/>
        <input type="text" class="date end" id="dateTo"/>
        <button onclick="loadData()"> Go </button>
    </p>
                <script>
                $('#basicExample .time').timepicker({
                    'showDuration': true,
                    'timeFormat': 'H:i:s',
                    'step': 60
                });

                $('#basicExample .date').datepicker({
                    'format': 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    'autoclose': true
                });

                var basicExampleEl = document.getElementById('basicExample');
                var datepair = new Datepair(basicExampleEl);
            </script>
</div>
<div id="chart_div" style="width:800; height:600"></div>
<footer id="DiversIT">
  <p id="DesignedBy">Designed by <a href="http://www.diversit.co" target="_blank">DiversIT</a></p>
  <p id="sitemap"><a href="SiteMap.html">Site Map</a></p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The only notable difference is some more script sources at the top and the script tags holding the initMap() function. I am baffled as to why this is happening.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why don't you post a working prototype or a jsFiddle of your problem?

Comment: Completely forgot to add the screenshots! Thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issues,  I moved my related scripts out of the head and placed them just above of the code I was having an issue with.

```
    <meta name="description" content="A javascript plugin for intelligently selecting date and time ranges inspired by Google Calendar." />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css" />

<script src="lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />

<script src="lib/pikaday.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/pikaday.css" />

<script src="lib/jquery.ptTimeSelect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jquery.ptTimeSelect.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script src="lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/site.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/site.css" />

<script src="dist/datepair.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jquery.datepair.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
            <script>
            $('#basicExample .time').timepicker({
                'showDuration': true,
                'timeFormat': 'H:i:s',
                'step': 60
            });

            $('#basicExample .date').datepicker({
                'format': 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                'autoclose': true
            });

            var basicExampleEl = document.getElementById('basicExample');
            var datepair = new Datepair(basicExampleEl);
        </script>
```